# How to retrieve tag value from quickfixj FIX.4.2 executionreport

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

I want to persist a **fix4.2** message to database by retrieving the value of each tag. I am having the **ExecutionReport** object of the fix message. 
I am retrieving the tag value of account using *exec.getString(1)* and this tag value is not present in the message so it is throwing FieldNotFound exception.
In Fiximate I found that account is not a mandatory field.

I also tried with *exec.getAccount().getValue()* but got same exception.
I found that every all these method throws FieldNotFound exception.

Is there any way to retrieve the tag value as **null** if that non-mandatory field is not present in the fix message.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Shadab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say which QuickFIX port you are using (e.g. the original QF for C++, QF/J for Java, QF/n for C#).

If a field is not required, you simply need to test for its presence first.

**C++:** `exec.isSetField(1)` or `exec.isSetField(field)`
 (there might also be a `exec.isSetAccount()`, not sure)

**Java:** `exec.isSetField(1)` or `exec.isSetAccount()` or `exec.isSetField(field)`

**C#:** `exec.IsSet(1)` or `exec.IsSetAccount()` or `exec.IsSetField(field)`